# How to install development version of R packages github repository

Tags: r, github, ggplot2

How can I install a package that is under development directly from a github repository and once installed how can I switch between development and CRAN versions?

The specific package I am interested in installing from git is ggplot2.

Comment: Possible related thread: [How to manage multiple package locations (folders) in R?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7993061/420055)

Comment: Related: [Installing non-public packages from Gitlab using devtools::install_git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27319207/562769)

Answer (score 86, accepted):

via Hadley at https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2

> ```
> install.packages("devtools")
>
> library(devtools)
>
> dev_mode(on=T)
>
> install_github("hadley/ggplot2")
>
> # use dev ggplot2 now
>
> # when finished do:
>
> dev_mode(on=F)  #and you are back to having stable ggplot2
> ```

Comment: The point of the question not only about how to install from Github (which is pretty clear) but also about how to switch between dev and release versions.  Presumably without reinstalling...

Comment: I just noticed that he wants to install and uninstall. Thanks for pointing that out. I am not sure the best way to do that but I edited above to show what I do.

Comment: PS: install_github requires the "make" command line tool which is installed on OS X by installing Xcode.

Comment: it changed a bit: `remotes::install_github("tidyverse/ggplot2")`

Answer (score 20):

I have the feeling that both previous answers miss the point of your question.

Consider this:

- You can control **where to install** packages via arguments to both `R CMD INSTALL` (via `-l`) and `install.packages()`.
- At run-time, you can control **where to load packages from** via `.libPaths()`.

So it really is just a matter of setting a few variables in your `.Rprofile` (or alike) to control this.

Answer (score 3):

for compile binaries install:

```
install.packages('xxx', repo='http://repo_adress')
```

for source install :

```
install.packages('xxx', repo='http://repo_adress', type='source')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
devtools::install_github("ggplot2")
```