# How to install a development version of R package from google code and/or launchpad.net?

Tags: r, installation, package

Some development versions of R packages are hosted on google code and/or launchpad.net.

Is it possible to install the newest release of these packages directly from google code and/or launchpad.net as from other repositories?

*ie. not downloading the source from the site through a browser and then attempting to install the source*

If so, how?

The package I wish to install is "igraph".

The development version of this package seems to be hosted at:

http://code.google.com/p/igraph/downloads/list
and
https://code.launchpad.net/~igraph/igraph/0.6-main

As a bonus, is it possible to do the same for packages hosted on sourceforge.net?

PS:  I believe this is different enough from my past question to warrant a separate question:  [How to install development version of R packages github repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656016/how-to-install-development-version-of-r-packages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `devtools` package, there is an `install_url` function which will automate the process of downloading the source code, building the package, and installing it.

```
install_url("http://igraph.googlecode.com/files/igraph_nightly_0.6-2689-20120412.tar.gz")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!  @Brian Diggs, how did you find this URL in the first place? I don't seem to be able to navigate to http://igraph.googlecode.com (or /files...). I was trying to do this with links found in http://code.google.com/p/igraph/downloads/list to no avail.

Comment: Clicking on `igraph_nightly_0.6-2689-20120412.tar.gz` on http://code.google.com/p/igraph/downloads/list takes you to `http://code.google.com/p/igraph/downloads/detail?name=igraph_nightly_0.6-2689-20120412.tar.gz&can=2&q=` which has the link to the actual tar.gz file on it.

Comment: thank you!  My browser starts download directly from http://code.google.com/p/igraph/downloads/detail?name=igraph_nightly_0.6-2689-20120412.tar.gz&can=2&q= and I could not seem to get it to provide me the link of the download file.

Comment: PS: install_url requires the "make" command line tool which is installed on OS X by installing Xcode.

Comment: It actually requires the full build system, including compilers if the package contains code to compile. `install_url` just makes the download/build/install process easier; all the steps still have to be done and prerequisites (build system, etc.) met.

Answer (score 1):

You must build from source, unless the developer provides a pre-built binary for your specific system (OS and R version).

Comment: Or a build service does: CRAN, R-Forge, RForge.net, Michael's Ubuntu PPA, and Don's for Debian all do that.

Answer (score 1):

To *not* download source requires someone to build the binary for you.  That only happens for CRAN, R-Forge and RForge.net packages, so you are out of luck.

Installing from source is the way to go.