# ggplot legend at top but below title?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way to make ggplot place the legend on top but below the title?

As an example...

[image]

..produced with the following code:

```
carrots<-list(Yield=c(345,226,74,559,288,194), 
              Field=c("A","B","C","D","E","F"), 
              Breed=rep(c("Long","Short"),each=3)) 
carrots<-data.frame(carrots) 

ggplot(carrots,aes(y=Yield,x=Field,fill=Breed)) + 
  geom_bar() + 
  opts(title="Title",
       legend.direction = "horizontal", 
       legend.position = "top") + 
         labs(fill="")
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated?

Comment: This has been fixed for the next version.

Comment: For now, if you have access to Adobe Illustrator, save the plot as eps e.g. `ggsave("plot.eps")` and then move the legend to the top in AI.

Comment: You can fine tune the elements of the grid arrangement using gridExtra package and saving the different elements (plot, legend, title in different objects).

Comment: This seems to be fixed in the dev version of ggplot2 : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656016/how-to-install-development-version-of-r-packages-github-repository     install.packages("devtools")

library(devtools)

dev_mode(on=T)

install_github("ggplot2")

# use dev ggplot2 now

# when finished do:

dev_mode(on=F) #and you are back to having stable ggplot2

Comment: @EtienneLow-Décarie with grid I would simply not use a title in ggplot2 but add it manually above the plot (e.g with `grid.arrange(plot, main = "title")`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit**  Ignore this. The issue is not longer a problem. 
But the code has been updated so that it no longer throws an error.

While waiting for the next version, you can fine tune within ggplot2. For instance:

```
ggplot(carrots, aes(y = Yield, x = Field, fill = Breed)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  theme(
     plot.margin = unit(c(2, 1, 1, 1), "cm"), 
     plot.title = element_text(size = 30, face = "bold", colour = "blue", vjust = 7), 
     legend.direction = "horizontal",
     legend.position = c(0.1, 1.05)) + 
   ggtitle("Title") +
  labs(fill = "")
```

Comment: Your original issue is fixed in the new version, released a few days ago.