# Placing legend above main title

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

Placing the legend above the main title in `ggplot2` when using `theme(legend.position = "top")` seemed to be the default (and unwanted) outcome in previous versions of ggplot: [ggplot legend at top but below title?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284717/ggplot-legend-at-top-but-below-title)

In the current version of `ggplot2`, the legend places itself *between* the plot and the main title when setting `theme(legend.position = "top")`. A small example:

```
d <- data.frame(x = 1:2, y = 1:2, z = c("a", "b")) 
ggplot(d, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = z)) + 
  geom_col() +
  ggtitle("My title") +
  theme(legend.position = "top")
```

[image]

How can I place the legend above main title?

Answer (score 10):

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, color=cyl)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = "Hey") +
  theme(plot.margin = margin(t=4,1,1,1, "lines")) +
  theme(legend.direction = "horizontal") +
  theme(legend.position = c(0.5, 1.2))
```

[image]

There are other ways as well, but this was the easiest one that came to mind.

Answer (score 6):

This requires a little more work than adjusting margins, but it should allow for more control over placement and sizing. I'm using functions from [`cowplot`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/): `get_legend` to extract the legend from the plot, and `plot_grid` to create a grid of these two `ggplot` elements.

After creating the plot `p` with a legend, `cowplot::get_legend(p)` then creates a `ggplot` object that is just the legend. Reposition them with `plot_grid` while adding a `theme` call that removes the legend from `p`. You'll probably want to tweak the heights and perhaps adjust margins.

```r
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(d, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = z)) + 
  geom_col() +
  ggtitle("My title") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") 

legend <- cowplot::get_legend(p)

cowplot::plot_grid(
  legend,
  p + theme(legend.position = "none"),
  ncol = 1, rel_heights = c(0.1, 1)
)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2018-10-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Or we can create a fake facet and put the plot title in it. After that do some tweaking to remove the strip facet and reduce the legend margin

```r
library(ggplot2)

d <- data.frame(x = 1:2, y = 1:2, z = c("a", "b")) 
d$Title <- "My title\n"

# default legend key text
p1 <- ggplot(d, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = z)) + 
  geom_col() +
  facet_grid(~ Title) +
  theme(strip.text.x = element_text(hjust = 0, vjust = 1,
                                    size = 14, face = 'bold'),
        strip.background = element_blank()) +
  theme(legend.margin = margin(5, 0, 0, 0),
        legend.box.margin = margin(0, 0, -10, 0)) +
  theme(legend.position = "top") +
  NULL

# legend key text at the bottom
p2 <- ggplot(d, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = z)) + 
  geom_col() +
  facet_grid(~ Title) +
  theme(strip.text.x = element_text(hjust = 0, vjust = 1,
                                    size = 14, face = 'bold'),
        strip.background = element_blank()) +
  theme(legend.margin = margin(5, 0, 0, 0),
        legend.box.margin = margin(0, 0, -10, 0)) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(label.position = "bottom",
                             title.position = "left", title.vjust = 1)) +
  theme(legend.position = "top") +
  NULL


library(patchwork)
p1 | p2
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2018-10-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1.9000)</sup>

Comment: Can you explain the `+ NULL` part? Never seen it before

Comment: `NULL` is there so that you can comment the line above it without breaking the code (the `+` at the end of each `ggplot` call can be a problem sometimes)