# Multivariate GARCH packages

Tags: r

I'm looking for a package that lets me estimate a vector autoregressive model with a mean equation consisting or perhaps an ARIMA and then a GARCH part. It is not of great importance what multivariate GARCH method is used and could thus be anything from a VECH to BEKK. I know that there is a package called mgarch out there but it does not seem to be in CRAN.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `mgarch` package is hosted on Github. It's available [here](https://github.com/vst/mgarch/).

In order to install R packages from Github you can use [devtools](https://github.com/hadley/devtools) from Hadley. This previous question address how to do this: [How to install development version of R packages github repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656016/how-to-install-development-version-of-r-packages-github-repository).

---

There is also [rugarch](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rugarch/index.html) which provides possibility of external regressors and also [ccgarch](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ccgarch/index.html) which deals with Conditional Correlation GARCH models.

A deep look in CRAN Finance's TaskView will give a good idea of the available packages in this area.

Comment: Is that the only multivariate garch package in R?