# Install R package from Atlassian Stash

Tags: r, git, devtools, bitbucket-server

I made an R package which is hosted on my employer's instance of Atlassian Stash. I have been telling other users to clone the repo and then use `devtools::install("<path-to-repo>")` to install the package.

How can I have users install the package *without* cloning the repository? Can I do this without hosting the code somewhere more accessible?

Comment: you could just email users a zipped file of the package files, and do `R CMD INSTALL <package_dir>` from the command line in linux, or other method of building packages from scratch in other OSes.

Comment: @Alex those solutions simply replace the the `devtools::install` command above, while still necessitating a prior step of obtaining the files from somewhere. I love the simplicity of installing from github with `devtools::install_github`, and my solution below gives a similar one-step process.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27319207/installing-non-public-packages-from-gitlab-using-devtoolsinstall-git) as a starting point, I discovered that you can use `devtools` with a Stash ssh url:

```
devtools::install_git("ssh://git@stash.yourdomain.com:1234/project/repo.git")
```

That will install from the latest commit on the `master` branch. You can also install a specific branch:

```
devtools::install_git("ssh://git@stash.yourdomain.com:1234/project/repo.git", branch="develop")
```

or tag:

```
devtools::install_git("ssh://git@stash.yourdomain.com:1234/project/repo.git", branch="v1.0")
```

(note you don't need the `tags/` prefix when using a tag)

This will only work if you have SSH keys for your machine on your Stash account. Using the http clone url will not work, because you can't authenticate properly.