# devtools::install_git Over SSH

Tags: r, git, ssh, devtools

I've written an R package that I keep in a (bare) git repository on an SSH server, and I want to be able to install it on a local machine without needing to clone the repository by hand.

I've attempted the following:

```
devtools::install_git("ssh://user_name@remote/path/to/repository")
```

but I get the error

```
    Downloading git repo ssh://user_name@remote/path/to/repository
    Error in git2r::clone(x$url, bundle, progress = FALSE) : 
    Error in 'git2r_clone': Failed to start SSH session: Unable to exchange encryption keys
```

I'm on a Windows 7 machine, using R 3.1.2, git2r version 0.11.0 and devtools version 1.9.1.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ran into this issue myself. I know this question is a bit old, but for anybody else running into the same issue (like me), here's what I've found.

## The Problem

Likely you don't have the library that [`git2r`](https://github.com/ropensci/git2r) (the package that `devtools` uses to interact with `git`) uses to communicate over SSH.

## The Solution

Install it. The example below assumes Ubuntu.

```
sudo apt-get install libssh2-1 libssh2-1-dev
```

`git2r` uses a library called LibSSH2 to enable transport over SSH. You can install it using your package manager if you're on Linux. <s>*NOTE* if you're on Windows, `git2r` does not support the SSH protocol yet :/</s> As of `git2r` version 0.11.0 (which uses an updated version of `libgit2`) [it looks like SSH is supported on Windows](https://github.com/ropensci/git2r/issues/131) as well. As of this edit, the newest version of `git2r` is 0.15, so if you don't have SSH support on Windows, try updating `git2r` (shout out to zeehio for the news).

**After you've installed LibSSH2** you'll need to reinstall the `git2r` package to enable SSH transport (since it's enabled/disabled during the package build).

### Sources

Issues on GitHub:

- https://github.com/hadley/devtools/issues/796
- https://github.com/ropensci/git2r/issues/140

## Why do I need LibSSH2 at all? `git` doesn't use it, right?

You're right! `git` doesn't use it (to my knowledge). However, [libgit2](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2#optional-dependencies), which is the pure C `git` API implementation that `git2r` uses, does.

Comment: _NOTE if you're on Windows, git2r does not support the SSH protocol yet :/_

That explains it, thanks for the answer!

Comment: Update: Since git2r 0.11.0 SSH transport is supported. `git2r::libgit2_features()` shows there is SSH support.

Comment: @zeehio Nice thanks for the update. I found the issue where they discuss support of SSH remotes on Windows. I'll update the answer.

Comment: "Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘LibSSH2’ is not available (for R version 3.4.3)"

Comment: @Mox you have to install libssh2 via you OS package manager. It’s not an R package.

Comment: I have never done that before. How does one do it in Windows 7?

Comment: @Mox the issue I linked in the answer on support for SSH on Windows in `git2r` seems to indicate you should be able to install it and have it statically bind rwinlib and OpenSSL. I’d checkout that projects wiki and readme to see how to install on windows specifically, but you could try just reinstalling git2r manually.