# How to push git repository through ssh using git2r?

Tags: r, git, ssh, libgit2

I'm trying to use `git2r` package (version 0.21.0).
I always use `ssh` connexions in my projects (GitHub and GitLab hosted): I can do `git pull/push` with both `RStudio IDE` and command line.
I have a standard Ubuntu Xenial configuration; my keys are stored in `~/.ssh` with standard names, my `ssh-agent` is running, and keys were added to `ssh-agent`. My problem is how to use the `git2r` package to push with `ssh`?

Here's what I do with a very basic workflow (work on `master`, remote name is `origin`):

```
library(git2r)
repo <- init("path_to_clone")
remote_url(repo)
```

> ```
> [1] "git@gitlab.com:account/repository.git"
> ```

```
credentials <- cred_ssh_key()
str(credentials)
```

> ```
> Formal class 'cred_ssh_key' [package "git2r"] with 3 slots
>   ..@ publickey : chr "/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
>   ..@ privatekey: chr "/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa"
>   ..@ passphrase: chr(0)
> ```

```
# some work, add(), commit()...
push(repo, "origin", "refs/heads/master", credentials = credentials)
```

> ```
>  Error in .local(object, ...) : 
>    Error in 'git2r_push': unsupported URL protocol
> ```

Is `ssh` protocol implemented in `git2r` package? Is there something I missed?`

---

**Edit:** I missed something, for sure. But, what?

```
libgit2_features()
```

> ```
> $threads
> [1] FALSE
> $https
> [1] FALSE
> $ssh
> [1] FALSE
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found what I missed. I forgot to install `libssh2-1-dev` library before installing `git2r`.
A similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33620182/2641825).

Install `libssh2-1-dev`:

```
sudo apt-get install libssh2-1-dev
```

Comment: Good catch. I incorrectly assumed it was an URL issue. +1