# Error in git checks when running devtools::release() in preparation for releasing package in R

Tags: r, devtools, cran

I am trying to release a package to CRAN using `devtools::release()`. Whenever I get to the step for `Running Git checks...` I get an error.

```
── Running Git checks for fitzRoy ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Current branch: master 
Checking uncommitted files... OK
Checking synchronisation with remote branch...
ERROR: Error in 'git2r_remote_fetch': unsupported URL protocol
```

I'm on a Mac. I've been using Git fine for the package and have no dramas committing, pushing and pulling.

I've tried updating devtools, git2r and also installing the latest version of Git but haven't had any luck.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Update - found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33294383/devtoolsinstall-git-over-ssh/33620182#33620182).

Basically - you need to install `libssh2`. On a Mac I followed the instructions [here](https://brewinstall.org/Install-libssh2-on-Mac-with-Brew/).

I then had to re-install `git2r` package for R by running the following

```
install.packages("git2r", type = "source")
```

After doing that and restarting R, the error went away.

Comment: On Ubuntu 18.04, I did `apt install libssh2-1 libssh2-1-dev libgit2-dev` using sudo and then reinstalled git2r. Not sure if all three were necessary, but leaving this in case is useful to someone.