# Connection reset by peer when trying to install private Gitlab R package

Tags: r, git, gitlab

I have created an R package that I have hosted in my company's Gitlab, and when I try to use the solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27319207/installing-non-public-packages-from-gitlab-using-devtoolsinstall-git) to install it I get the following error:

```
Installation failed: Error in 'git2r_clone': SSL error: syscall failure: Connection reset by peer
```

A coworker tried to run the same command I did and they managed to do it. Why is this error occurring to me?

Comment: Are you doing it over a wired connection or wireless?

Comment: I'm using a wireless connection @muecas

Comment: I've seen this error cloning repos, try a wired connection. Just to give it a try.

Comment: I'll give that a try!

Comment: @muecas i tried a wired connection here and it still failed :(

Comment: maybe u can compare your `git config --list` with your coworker. maybe SSL is disabled on coworker's git?

Answer (score 1):

Check your Git version and your %PATH% (Windows) or $PATH.

You must have a recent Git, for supporting the right OpenSSL version, and you must not reference any other openssl in your PATH which might be too old.

Comment: Updated git and all my $PATH has is `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/pedro/Library/Python/2.7/bin` but it still doesn't work

Comment: @PedroCarvalho which version of Git are using? On which OS?

Comment: 2.17.0, on Mac OS X (whichever the latest one is)

Comment: Would the issue persists with Git 2.18?