# RMySQL dbWriteTable runs into problems with file path on Windows 7 x64

Tags: r, rmysql

### The setting

I run a local instance of MariaDB 5.5 where I created a database which has two tables. I have to fill these tables with data that is stored in a few thousand `.RData` files. Each file stores `data.frames` that have between a few thousand and more than a million rows.

Using `RMySQL` and the function `dbWriteTable` seems to be the most straightforward solution. I use RevolutionR's 3.1.1 build (8.0 beta). The operating system is Win7 x64.

The table in MariaDB has two columns: `ID` and `VALUE`, its name is `TAB`. The data to be stored are in the object `data.tab`.

### What I do

I proceed as follows:

```
data.tab <- data.frame(ID = c(1:3), VAL = c(7:9))
db.con <- dbConnect(drv = MySQL(), user = "root", password = "myPasswrd", dbname="myDBname")
dbWriteTable(conn = db.con, name = "TAB", value = data.tab, append=TRUE, row.names=FALSE, field.types=character(ID="INT",VAL="FLOAT"))
```

Or equivalently, via a temporary csv file that I create:

```
dbWriteTable(conn = db.con, name = "TAB", value = 'tmp.csv', append=TRUE, row.names=FALSE, field.types=character(ID="INT",VAL="INT"))
```

### The problem

Calling the second line in the above snippet causes the following error to be thrown:

```
Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : 
sdbi114c7f07039' not found (Errcode: 22)tempRtmpE9YwdP
```

Calling the third line (via temporary csv file) results in a similar error, where the path is printed with backslashes stripped out. This turns out to be related to path expansion. Debugging and printing `statement` yields:

"LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\TEMP\\Rtemp\\RtmpE9YwdP\\rsdbi114c7f07039'  INTO TABLE `TAB` LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'   (`ID`, `VALUE`);"

Thus it seems that the escapes of backslashes (`\\`) and `\r` seem to be the problem. I don't unfortunately know how to deal with this.

Traceback (in call order):

```
1: dbWriteTable(conn = db.con, name = "t_ftr", value = fut.tbl, append = TRUE, row.names = FALSE,
2: .valueClassTest({standardGeneric("dbWriteTable")}, "logical", "dbWriteTable")
3: is(object, Cl)
4: is(object, Cl)
5: .local(conn, name, value, ...)
6: dbGetQuery(conn, sql)
7: dbGetQuery(conn, sql)
8: dbSendQuery(conn, statement, ...)
9: .valueClassTest(standardGeneric("dbSendQuery"), "DBIResult", "dbSendQuery")
10: is(object, Cl)
11: is(object, Cl)
12: .local(conn, statement, ...)
13: .Call(RS_MySQL_exec, conn@Id, as.character(statement))
```

### EDIT

If in the interactive debugger at step 11 in `statement` I replace `\\` with `/` in the path, the data is written to the database correctly.

Comment: Same problem here. Standard R 3.1.2 and RMySQL 0.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a problem in RMySQL. I fixed the issue and submitted a pull request on GitHub:

https://github.com/rstats-db/RMySQL/issues/29

For me it works now, on my computer. You can compile and install [the development version from GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656016/how-to-install-development-version-of-r-packages-github-repository), or wait till a new version of the package is released on CRAN.

Edit: It's on CRAN now, version 0.10.1