# fetchData function no longer in mosaic package

Tags: r

I am using R 3.2.2 and installed the `mosaic` package. I then used the `fetchData` function as follows:

```
data<-fetchData(1,c("Web_scraping","Data_mining"))
```

I get the following error:

> Error: Use fetchData() from the `fetch' package instead.

When I try to install the `fetch` package, an error says:

> Warning in install.packages :
>         package ‘fetch’ is not available (for R version 3.2.2)

I found documentation that the `mosaic` package was dropping `fetchData` in R 3.2.2, but couldn't find what package I should use to run the function properly.

Comment: Did [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34076618/1167750) end up helping at all? Something still not working?

Answer (score 3):

### Fetch

It appears that the `fetch` package is currently available via GitHub at https://github.com/ProjectMOSAIC/fetch.

### Installation

To install `fetch` from GitHub:

1. Open up your R console
2. Install `devtools` *(if not already installed)* [with this command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9656182)*:

   `install.packages("devtools")`
3. Type `y` if going through the `devtools` installer
4. Install `fetch` [with this command](https://github.com/ProjectMOSAIC/fetch/blob/master/README.md):

   `devtools::install_github("ProjectMOSAIC/fetch")`

### Basic Usage

If successful, `fetch` should be accessible by requiring the `fetch` package

```
require("ProjectMOSAIC/fetch")
```

and calling `fetchData()` like this:

```
data <- fetch::fetchData( ... )
```

---

* **Note:** [According to Etienne Low-Décarie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9656182), you'll need to have the `make` command available on your system before running the `install.packages("devtools")` command.

Answer (score 3):

My students have been running into this problem trying to use the textbook code from Statistical Modeling: A Fresh Approach, this semester. I'm not familiar with the syntax used in the original question (with the number as the first argument), but this does not appear to be supported syntax in the `fetch::fetchData()` function. The workflow that we have been using to get around this (slightly simpler than summea's answer) is:

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("ProjectMOSAIC/fetch")
data <- fetch::fetchData("whickham.csv")
```

Note that I cannot reproduce the example in the original question, as I get different error/warning messages:

```
data<-fetch::fetchData(1,c("Web_scraping","Data_mining"))
```

With this as the error/warning:

```
Error in if (show.path) return(get("path", envir = .fetchEnvironment)) : 
  argument is not interpretable as logical
In addition: Warning message:
In if (show.path) return(get("path", envir = .fetchEnvironment)) :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

I hope fetch is on its way to being on CRAN, and listed as a dependency of mosaic, as this is currently causing headaches in my class.