# How to add image to ggplot2 under the grid?

Tags: r, ggplot2

The most popular (and simplest) way to adding image to the ggplot2 graph is `annotation_custom`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(png)
library(grid)

img <- readPNG(system.file("img", "Rlogo.png", package="png"), TRUE)
gpp <- rasterGrob(img, interpolate=TRUE)
gpp$width <- unit(1, "npc") 
    gpp$height <- unit(1, "npc")
df <- data.frame(x=seq(1,2,0.01),y=seq(1,2,0.01))
ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y)) + 
    annotation_custom(gpp, xmin=1, xmax=2.5, ymin=1, ymax=1.5) +
    geom_point()
```

In this way, image will be placed over the scale grid.

How to place image *under* the grid, but with bindings to the coords, not to the borders of the plot?

Comment: You mean like `p <- ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y))+ theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1,1,8,1), "lines")) + annotation_custom(gpp, xmin=.9, xmax=1.1, ymin=.7, ymax=.9); gt <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p)); gt$layout$clip[gt$layout$name == "panel"] <- "off"; grid.draw(gt)`? There are numerous examples on SO.

Comment: `+ theme(panel.ontop=TRUE)` in dev version

Comment: `gt$layout$clip[gt$layout$name == "panel"] <- "off";` did not change anything, but `theme(panel.ontop=TRUE, panel.background = element_rect(colour = NA,fill="transparent"))` in _dev_ version working as required. Thanks! Is it possible to get this behavior in the stable ggplot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible in the *development version* of ggplot2.

How to install it see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9656182/4265407

Minimal working example:

```
library(devtools)
dev_mode(on=T)

library(ggplot2)
library(png)
library(grid)

img <- readPNG(system.file("img", "Rlogo.png", package="png"), TRUE)
gpp <- rasterGrob(img, interpolate=TRUE)
gpp$width <- unit(1, "npc") 
gpp$height <- unit(1, "npc")
df <- data.frame(x=seq(1,2,0.01),y=seq(1,2,0.01))
ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y)) + 
    annotation_custom(gpp, xmin=1, xmax=2.5, ymin=1, ymax=1.5) +
    geom_point() + theme(panel.ontop=TRUE,
    panel.background = element_rect(colour = NA,fill="transparent"))
```