# Can't move timePlot legend when using R openair

Tags: r, graph, legend

I cannot seem to move the legend from the bottom of my graph when using `timePlot` from R `openair`. Can anyone assist?

Here is my script and some data:

```
library(openair)
timeozone <- import(npsfiles[2], date="year", date.format = "%Y", header=TRUE, na.strings="NA")
timePlot(timeozone, pollutant = c("BIBEKB", "MACAGO", "MACAHM", "VOYASB"), group = TRUE, ylab = "Ozone (ppbv)", key.columns = 1)
```

Data:

```
Year   BIBEKB

1990      70.25

1991      59.25

1992      62.5

1993     64.25

1994     76

1995     68.25

1996     78.375

1997     66.25
```

I have tried:

```
auto.key = list(space = "right")
space = "right"
key.position = "right"
```

I have also tried putting the legend specification outside the timePlot line of code, but I am hoping to be able to get it to work with the location specification in the timePlot function. Thanks for any help you can provide:

```
plot.new()
legend(1, -1, c("BIBEKB","MACAGO","MACAHM", "VOYASB"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw that "key.position =" function option was added in github repo of openair [timePlot](https://github.com/davidcarslaw/openair/blob/master/R/timePlot.R)

But it's developer version. So you can try and install it manually. May be it'll help you!

[How to install from Github repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656016/how-to-install-development-version-of-r-packages-github-repository)