# Using two versions of openxlsx forks in same file

Tags: r, excel, openxlsx

I am using excel templates to collect data from various people. To minmize the chances of people changing the structure of the templates I wanted to protect the sheets, but still allow them to fill in the data values that I want. At the same time I also use the `dataValidation`command that one can only use once in the `Cran`version ([Stack Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48844046/openxlsx-multiple-validations-corrupts-output-file))

I was happy that i found a forked version of the openxlsx package that has included a function `protectWorksheet` to enable sheet protection, [Link](https://rdrr.io/github/awalker89/openxlsx/). But the `awalker89` fork has not fixed the issue with the `dataValidation`function, that would be fixed in the `tkunstek`fork.

I found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988559/how-do-you-use-multiple-versions-of-the-same-r-package) about using different version of a package, but it seems to be rather complicated and I am afraid this would then not work, because I would be mixing two different version in one excel file.

Can I install `openxlsx` version under different names like `openxlsx_awalker` and openxlsx_tkunstek` and then load them parallely to to what I want to do? How would I do this?

I could also open the excel file first with the `tkunstek`package, enable the dataValidations and then open it again with the `awalker`package to protect the sheet, but still not sure if the files would work thereafter.

I would image a MWE as follows

```
library(openxlsx_awalker)
library(openxlsx_tkunstek)

wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "S1")
writeDataTable(wb, 1, x = data.frame(iris[1:30,],yesno="Yes",highlow="Low"))

addWorksheet(wb, "Drop-down values", visible=FALSE)
yesno_values_df = data.frame("YESNO" = c("Yes", "No"))
yesno.labels<-"'Drop-down values'!$A$2:$A$3"
source_values_df = data.frame("Sources" = c("High", "Low"))
highlow.labels<-"'Drop-down values'!$B$2:$B$3"
writeData(wb, sheet = "Drop-down values", x =yesno_values_df, startCol =1)
writeData(wb, sheet = "Drop-down values", x =source_values_df, startCol =2)

openxlsx_tkunstek::dataValidation(wb, "S1", col = 6, rows = 1:10,
               type = "list", value =yesno.labels)
openxlsx_tkunstek::dataValidation(wb, "S1", col = 7, rows = 1:10,
               type = "list", value =highlow.labels)
# Formatting cells / columns is allowed , but inserting / deleting columns is protected:

openxlsx_awalker::protectWorksheet(wb, "S1", protect = TRUE, lockFormattingCells = FALSE, lockFormattingColumns = FALSE, lockInsertingColumns = TRUE, lockDeletingColumns = TRUE)


saveWorkbook(wb, "test.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```