# ggplot, ggsave & coord_map/quickmap: how to save large spatial objects and get the projection right?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, gis, r-sp

I have a largish polyline shapefile (Bavarian rivers, which can be accessed [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/7bs2x2rx1md7vwn/AACJ2JS1ibW0PwikUehJ7TAMa?dl=0)) which I would like to plot and save via ggplot. This can easily be done via e.g. this code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(rgdal)
library(sp)
library(rgeos)

riv <- readOGR(paste0(getwd(),"\\rivers_bavaria","rivers_bavaria"))
riv1 <- subset(riv,WDM=="1310"|WDM=="1320")
riv2 <- subset(riv,WDM=="1330")

p <- ggplot() +
  geom_line(data=riv1, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group), color="dodgerblue", size=1) +
  geom_line(data=riv2, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group), color="dodgerblue")

ggsave(paste0(getwd(),"\\riv.tiff",p,device="tiff",units="cm",dpi=300)
```

This is not exactly efficient, due to the large file size, but it works. However, without further specifying aspect ratio or projection, the dimensions of the output file are defined by the plot window - not desirable for maps. This can be remedied by using `coord_quickmap()`.

```
p1 <- ggplot() +
  geom_line(data=riv1, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group), color="dodgerblue", size=1) +
  geom_line(data=riv2, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group), color="dodgerblue") +
  coord_quickmap()
p1
```

Unfortunately, the projection is completely off. I have tried `coord_map()` for a better result, but due to the large file size, it takes forever and is therefore not a realistic option. Simplifying the polyline via `gLinemerge()` produces a much smaller object, but cannot be handled by ggplot, as it is a SpatialLines object. Using `fortify()` or `data.frame()` to coerce it into a ggplot-friendly data frame format also produces `Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class SpatialLines`.

I'm therefore desperately looking for a workflow that will allow me to plot and save this kind of spatial data in good quality with ggplot. Any suggestions will be much appreciated!

Comment: Do you mind an `sf` solution? It makes what you're doing—subsetting, changing projections, plotting in ggplot—very easy and straightforward

Comment: Yes, please - otherwise all my previous work goes to waste!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick walkthrough with `sf`. I recommend the `sf` vignettes and docs to see more details of any of the functions. I'm first reading the shapefile in as an `sf` object using `sf::st_read`, then filtering, mutating, and selecting the same as you would in `dplyr` to get a smaller version of the shape.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)

rivers_sf <- st_read("rivers_bavaria/rivers_bavaria.shp") %>%
  filter(WDM %in% c("1310", "1320", "1330")) %>%
  mutate(name2 = ifelse(WDM == "1330", "river 2", "river 1")) %>%
  select(name2, NAM, geometry)
```

The object is pretty big, and will be very slow to plot, so I simplified it by uniting the geometries by name, then using `st_simplify`. There's also `rmapshaper::ms_simplify`, which uses Mapshaper and which I prefer for better control over how much information you keep. Then to show a CRS transformation, I picked a projection from [Spatial Reference](http://spatialreference.org/) for Germany.

```
riv_simple <- rivers_sf %>%
  group_by(name2, NAM) %>%
  summarise(geometry = st_union(geometry)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  st_simplify(preserveTopology = T, dTolerance = 1e6) %>%
  st_transform(31493)
```

The dev version of `ggplot2` on GitHub has a function `geom_sf` for plotting different types of `sf` objects. To get this version, run `devtools::install_github("tidyverse/ggplot2")`.

`geom_sf` has some quirks, and works a little differently from other geoms, but it's pretty versatile. I believe it's being included in the next CRAN release. `geom_sf` has corresponding `stat_sf` and `coord_sf`. By default, it plots graticule lines; to turn those off, add `coord_sf(ndiscr = F)`.

```
ggplot(riv_simple) +
  geom_sf(aes(size = name2), color = "dodgerblue", show.legend = "line") +
  scale_size_manual(values = c("river 1" = 1, "river 2" = 0.5)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  coord_sf(ndiscr = F)
```

[image]

Hope that helps you get started!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your work! I really like the easy table format of the sf objects. Unfortunately, I was not able to install the dev version of ggplot (following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656016/how-to-install-development-version-of-r-packages-github-repository) advice). Is there no other way to simplify large spatial objects for plotting with ggplot?

Comment: That post is outdated; I'll amend my answer. The `tidyverse` repos are now at "tidyverse/ggplot2" (or fill in whatever other package name in the ecosystem), not "hadley/ggplot2"