# Is it necessary to remove the installed version before installing another version of the same package in R?

Tags: r, package

Say I want to install dev version of `data.table`, the recommended [command](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) is:

```
remove.packages("data.table")
install.packages("data.table", type = "source",
    repos = "http://Rdatatable.github.io/data.table")
```

My question is: Is it necessary to remove the currently installed version first? Is there any danger if I install the new version without removing exisiting version?

Comment: Have you tried it? This seems to be a dupe of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988559/how-do-you-use-multiple-versions-of-the-same-r-package)

Comment: @DavidArenburg, my question is not about install multiple versions of the same package at the same time. A single installation is fine for me. I usually just install  the new version (overwrite the old version) without removing the old one with `remove.package` first. I wonder whether it is safe to do so.

Comment: I was warrying that the after new installation in the same dir, whether some relics of the old version in the same might be in conflict with the new installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you install a package into the default library, a new version completely replaces the old version. You don't need to remove the old version manually.

Of course, this requires the package to not be loaded when you install the new version.