# Best way to reference a locally created r package in a second r project

Tags: r, rstudio

I have created a r package containing some functions, let's call it functionPackage.  I have a second project that needs to reference the functionPackage.  I can successfully install the functionPackage by pointing to the functionPackage folder and the install process creates a folder in AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.3\functionPackage.

If I want to make changes to functionPackage how do I do that and have the references in the second project refresh?

If I open the function project in RStudio, make my changes and try to rebuild it fails saying ERROR: cannot remove earlier installation, is it in use?  I tried remove.packages which completes successfully but I still get an Access Denied error when it tries to rename a file in AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.3\functionPackage folder.  So I then have to close down and reopen all RStudio sessions before I can re install the updated package.

How can I set up my environment to make this scenario easier to manage?

Comment: That's more-or-less correct--you can't update a package while an R session is using it. You don't need to close RStudio, but you do need to restart the R session to do a package update. [There are ways to have different versions of an R package installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988559/how-do-you-use-multiple-versions-of-the-same-r-package), and perhaps you could [detach one version (link to FAQ)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6979917/903061) and then load another...

Comment: but overall this sounds like much **more** work to me than simply restarting R before building and installing the updated package. If you have a decent workflow restarting R should not be a big deal. (You can do this in RStudio from the menu `Session/Restart R`)

Comment: And hopefully you are using a version control tool like Git to manage the versions and change to your package.

Comment: Being used to project references in visual studio this all seems a bit cumbersome but I guess it is what it is.  Thanks for your response and the links above.